# android: camera zoom and opengl

Tags: android, opengl-es, zooming

I want to add pinch/zoom and pan to my 2D application which is written using opengl . it consist of several shape , images , etc . how could I do that ? camera zoom possibly ? another option is also scaling but I don't think that possible because I have several objects in the screen and it would be really hard to do that.

please give me some examples or simple tutorial  . I already find some examples on scaling but couldn't find any for camera movement.

Comment: How do you create your projection-matrix?